# c# array with nullable index from query

Tags: c#, arrays, nullable

I have this query:

```
var result = (from i in dc.Sis
                      where i.Tid == tid && i.Sid == sid
                      select i);
```

And I want to access an array using this index: `result.num` which is nullable.

```
string ype = YPes[result.First().num]; //if index is null then ype = null
```

But I receive this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The index of an item in an array cannot be `null`

Comment: Which element do you want when `result.num` is `null` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman if index is null then I want null value to be passed to ype string

Comment: Then InBetween guessed right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, how do you expect to index into an array with an index equal to `null`? It *is* a valid `int?` value. Does this make sense to you?:

```
string ype = YPes[null];
```

You have to cater for both possible cases:

```
var ype = result.num.HasValue ? YPes[result.num.Value]: default(string);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but now I receive :  'System.Nullable<int>.value' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: @alxem it's suppose to be `Value` with a capital V.

Comment: @alxem `Value`, not `value`.

Comment: Now I think , you need to explain it loud. how do you access it . `result.num.HasValue`.   I'm sure you'll see where the error is

Comment: @InBetween : From the beginning, I see this `var result = (from i in dc.Sis where i.Tid == tid && i.Sid == sid select i);`  It was OP who written this `result.num` but you have posted an answer, so you should post correct WORKING answer.

Answer (score -1):

check before using that variable. it is null or not.

```
if(result.First().num.HasValue)
{
  string ype = YPes[result.First().num];
}
```

Comment: @InBetween : this is the only way, because you can not pass null value to array index.   It's not MAGIC , it's LOGIC .

Comment: Explain, out loud, your code to a rubber duck, I'm sure you'll see where the error is.